# После отправки формы, следующий раз аякс не срабатывает

Tags: jquery, ajax, форма

Вот сам скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        /* на все формы */
        $('#ajax_form').submit(function(e){
        //отменяем стандартное действие при отправке формы
        e.preventDefault();
        //берем из формы метод передачи данных
        var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
        //получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
        var m_action=$(this).attr('action');
        //то есть в стандартном формате передачи данных формы
        var m_data=$(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: m_method,
            url: m_action,
            data: m_data,
                success: function(result){
                    $('#content .row-fluid').html(result);
                }
            });
        });

});
```

После отправки формы, она возвращается с новыми данными и при повторном нажатии аякс уже не срабатывает.
Сама форма одна и та же, тоесть только подставляются новые данные, поэтому у меня идеи кончились почему такое может быть.

Comment: Форма случайно находится не внутри `$('#content .row-fluid')`?

Comment: В нем, вместо старой формы появляется таже форма, но с новыми данными, на то же место

Comment: Ну правильно, у новой формы уже нет js-обработчика. Нужно писать по другому, через `.on()`

Comment: Если честно я не понял как через .on() :)
Что именно не так для данного случая?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно ловить события через [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#content').on('submit', '#ajax_form', function(e){
        //отменяем стандартное действие при отправке формы
        e.preventDefault();
        //берем из формы метод передачи данных
        var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
        //получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
        var m_action=$(this).attr('action');
        //то есть в стандартном формате передачи данных формы
        var m_data=$(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: m_method,
            url: m_action,
            data: m_data,
                success: function(result){
                    $('#content .row-fluid').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: А вот еще похожая ситуация, как с этим можно обойтись?

     $('#drop a').click(function(){
         // Имитация клика по input
         $(this).parent().find('input').click();
         $.get('/algo/get/get_photo_user.php', {}, function(data){
          $('.photo_user_list').html(data);
         });
     });